# Netbeans code for Postgresql and Eclipselink - identifying relation question

Tags: postgresql, orm, netbeans, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have the following database tables:

- party, with a pk "pty_id" connected to a sequence for generating pk values.
- person with a fpk "prs_pty_id" in an identifying relation to party.pty_id.
- company ... which is not involved at the moment, but obviously this is kindof sub-superclass setup, and it could probably have been implemented with the subclassing mechanism in postgresql, but that's for another day.

So, I use Netbeans 6.9.1 to generate JPA entity classes and controller/dao code to handle this. It works just nice, I only have to add one annotation to the Party Entity bean: @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY). This is not needed for the Person entity bean, because it should always have the pk value of the Party that it is connected to.

So here is what I do to create a person:

```
PartyJpaController parController = new PartyJpaController();
PersonJpaController perController = new PersonJpaController();
Party par = new Party();
Person per = new Person();
par.setComment("jalla");
per.setName("Per Vers");
parController.create(par);
per.setPrsPtyId(par.getPtyId()); // <== why do I need to set this ...
Long partyId = par.getPtyId();
par.setPerson(per); // <== ... when this explicitly expresses the relationship?
perController.create(per);
parController.edit(par);

Party foundParty = parController.findParty(partyId);

Person foundPerson = foundParty.getPerson();
System.err.println(foundPerson.getName());
```

This works just fine. But why do I have to explicitly set the pk of the Person bean? It is in an identifying relationship with the Party. If I skip it, I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An instance of a null PK has been incorrectly provided for this find operation.
```

in perController.create(per), which is code generated by Netbeans:

```
EntityManager em = null;
try {
    em = getEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Party party = person.getParty();
    if (party != null) {
        party = em.getReference(party.getClass(), party.getPtyId()); // <== Exception thrown here
        person.setParty(party);
    }
    em.persist(person);
    if (party != null) {
        party.setPerson(person);
        party = em.merge(party);
    }
    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

So, I suppose the Netbeans-generated code is not quite tuned for identifying relationships? What's the best way to code this?

Software used: Eclipselink version 2.1.1 Postgresql 8.4 Netbeans 6.9.1 Java/JDK 1.6.0_21

Here are my beans, they're generated by netbeans 6.9.1 from schema, except the @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) in Party, which I've added in order to use the serial/sequence pk generation in postgresql.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package com.martinsolaas.webmarin.jpa;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 *
 * @author jms
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "person", catalog = "webmarin", schema = "webmarin")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByPrsPtyId", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.prsPtyId = :prsPtyId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByName", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByCellphone", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.cellphone = :cellphone"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByOfficephone", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.officephone = :officephone")})
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "prs_pty_id", nullable = false)
    @MapsId
    private Long prsPtyId;
    @Column(name = "name", length = 255)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "cellphone", length = 55)
    private String cellphone;
    @Column(name = "officephone", length = 55)
    private String officephone;
    @JoinColumn(name = "prs_pty_id", referencedColumnName = "pty_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Party party;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(Long prsPtyId) {
        this.prsPtyId = prsPtyId;
    }

    public Long getPrsPtyId() {
        return prsPtyId;
    }

    public void setPrsPtyId(Long prsPtyId) {
        this.prsPtyId = prsPtyId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCellphone() {
        return cellphone;
    }

    public void setCellphone(String cellphone) {
        this.cellphone = cellphone;
    }

    public String getOfficephone() {
        return officephone;
    }

    public void setOfficephone(String officephone) {
        this.officephone = officephone;
    }

    public Party getParty() {
        return party;
    }

    public void setParty(Party party) {
        this.party = party;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (prsPtyId != null ? prsPtyId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Person)) {
            return false;
        }
        Person other = (Person) object;
        if ((this.prsPtyId == null && other.prsPtyId != null) || (this.prsPtyId != null && !this.prsPtyId.equals(other.prsPtyId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.martinsolaas.webmarin.jpa.Person[prsPtyId=" + prsPtyId + "]";
    }

}
```

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package com.martinsolaas.webmarin.jpa;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 *
 * @author jms
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "party", catalog = "webmarin", schema = "webmarin")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Party.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Party p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Party.findByPtyId", query = "SELECT p FROM Party p WHERE p.ptyId = :ptyId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Party.findByComment", query = "SELECT p FROM Party p WHERE p.comment = :comment")})
public class Party implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "pty_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long ptyId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "comment", nullable = false, length = 2147483647)
    private String comment;
    @JoinTable(name = "party_relationship", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "parent_pty_id", referencedColumnName = "pty_id", nullable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "child_pty_id", referencedColumnName = "pty_id", nullable = false)})
    @ManyToMany
    private List partyList;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "partyList")
    private List partyList1;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "party")
    private Person person;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "party")
    private Company company;

    public Party() {
    }

    public Party(Long ptyId) {
        this.ptyId = ptyId;
    }

    public Party(Long ptyId, String comment) {
        this.ptyId = ptyId;
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public Long getPtyId() {
        return ptyId;
    }

    public void setPtyId(Long ptyId) {
        this.ptyId = ptyId;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public List getPartyList() {
        return partyList;
    }

    public void setPartyList(List partyList) {
        this.partyList = partyList;
    }

    public List getPartyList1() {
        return partyList1;
    }

    public void setPartyList1(List partyList1) {
        this.partyList1 = partyList1;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (ptyId != null ? ptyId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Party)) {
            return false;
        }
        Party other = (Party) object;
        if ((this.ptyId == null && other.ptyId != null) || (this.ptyId != null && !this.ptyId.equals(other.ptyId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.martinsolaas.webmarin.jpa.Party[ptyId=" + ptyId + "]";
    }

}
```

Eventually, here is the schema SQL

```
CREATE SEQUENCE webmarin.party_pty_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE webmarin.party (
                pty_id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('webmarin.party_pty_id_seq'),
                comment TEXT NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT pty_pk PRIMARY KEY (pty_id)
);


ALTER SEQUENCE webmarin.party_pty_id_seq OWNED BY webmarin.party.pty_id;

CREATE TABLE webmarin.company (
                cmp_pty_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
                name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT cmp_pk PRIMARY KEY (cmp_pty_id)
);


CREATE TABLE webmarin.party_relationship (
                parent_pty_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
                child_pty_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT ptr_pk PRIMARY KEY (parent_pty_id, child_pty_id)
);


CREATE TABLE webmarin.person (
                prs_pty_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
                name VARCHAR(255),
                cellphone VARCHAR(55),
                officephone VARCHAR(55),
                CONSTRAINT prs_pk PRIMARY KEY (prs_pty_id)
);


ALTER TABLE webmarin.party_relationship ADD CONSTRAINT parent_party_party_relationship_fk
FOREIGN KEY (parent_pty_id)
REFERENCES webmarin.party (pty_id)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE webmarin.party_relationship ADD CONSTRAINT child_party_party_relationship_fk
FOREIGN KEY (child_pty_id)
REFERENCES webmarin.party (pty_id)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE webmarin.person ADD CONSTRAINT party_person_fk
FOREIGN KEY (prs_pty_id)
REFERENCES webmarin.party (pty_id)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE webmarin.company ADD CONSTRAINT party_company_fk
FOREIGN KEY (cmp_pty_id)
REFERENCES webmarin.party (pty_id)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA 2.0 improved considerably the support of *derived identifiers* with the `Id` and `MapsId` annotations (they should be preferred now) that you can use on `XxxToOne` associations. Below one of the example taken from the specification:

> #### 2.4.1.3 Examples of Derived Identities
>
> ...
>
> **Example 4:**
>
> The parent entity has a simple primary
>   key:
>
> ```
> @Entity
> public class Person {
>     @Id String ssn;
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> **Case (a):** The dependent entity has a single primary key attribute which
>   is mapped by the relationship
>   attribute. The primary key of
>   `MedicalHistory` is of type `String`.
>
> ```
> @Entity
> public class MedicalHistory {
>     // default join column name is overridden
>     @Id
>     @OneToOne
>     @JoinColumn(name="FK")
>     Person patient;
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> Sample query:
>
> ```
> SELECT m
> FROM MedicalHistory m
> WHERE m.patient.ssn = '123-45-6789'
> ```
>
> **Case (b):** The dependent entity has a single primary key attribute
>   corresponding to the relationship
>   attribute. The primary key attribute
>   is of the same basic type as the
>   primary key of the parent entity. The
>   `MapsId` annotation applied to the
>   relationship attribute indicates that
>   the primary key is mapped by the
>   relationship attribute.
>
> ```
> @Entity
> public class MedicalHistory {
>     @Id String id; // overriding not allowed
>     ...
>     // default join column name is overridden
>     @MapsId
>     @JoinColumn(name="FK")
>     @OneToOne Person patient;
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> Sample query:
>
> ```
> SELECT m
> FROM MedicalHistory m WHERE m.patient.ssn = '123-45-6789'
> ```

I think that the `MapsId` might be what you're looking for.

**Follow-up:** Instead of this:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "prs_pty_id", nullable = false)
    @MapsId
    private Long prsPtyId;
    @Column(name = "name", length = 255)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "cellphone", length = 55)
    private String cellphone;
    @Column(name = "officephone", length = 55)
    private String officephone;
    @JoinColumn(name = "prs_pty_id", referencedColumnName = "pty_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Party party;
    ...
}
```

Try this:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "prs_pty_id", nullable = false)
    private Long prsPtyId;
    @Column(name = "name", length = 255)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "cellphone", length = 55)
    private String cellphone;
    @Column(name = "officephone", length = 55)
    private String officephone;
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "prs_pty_id", referencedColumnName = "pty_id")
    @OneToOne
    private Party party;
    ...
}
```

#### References

- JPA 2.0 specification

  - Section 2.4.1 "Primary Keys Corresponding to Derived Identities"
  - Section 2.4.1.1 "Specification of Derived Identities"
  - Section 2.4.1.2 "Mapping of Derived Identities"
  - Section 2.4.1.3 "Examples of Derived Identities"
- JPA Wikibook

  - [3.2 Primary Keys through OneToOne Relationships](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_Relationships)
  - [3.2.2 JPA 2.0](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#JPA_2.0)

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work as expected, Eclipse-link still tries to create a person row with a null pk. Sample code:

            em.getTransaction().begin();
            Party par = new Party();
            Person per = new Person();
            par.setComment("Nice");
            per.setName("Per Vers");
            par.setPerson(per);
            em.persist(par);
            em.getTransaction().commit();

No luck with Hibernate either.

Comment: @user275886 Please edit your question to show your entities and mappings. The mappings are the "problem", not the code used to persist so if you don't show them them, I can't say anything.

Comment: I'll do that as soon as I can, until then, entitiets are basically just as netbeans generate them, and I don't use any special mappings.

Comment: I've added bean source and DDL for the schema now, I don't have any particular mapping configuration, only a minimal persistence.xml declaring eclipselink as provider, connection data etc. Thanks for looking into this :-)

Comment: Ok, getting closer I think, now I get "Exception Description: There should be one non-read-only mapping defined for the primary key field [webmarin.webmarin.person.prs_pty_id]." So it seems I need a mapping, but how and where and ... ?

Comment: @user275886 Try to remove the `nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false` from the JoinColumn annotation.

Comment: Didn't work, still pts_pty_id is null, while I want pty_id from party to be used automatically. No go with Hibernate either, so I must be doing something wrong here ...

Comment: OK, finally got it working ... started over by generating entitybeans with netbeans, added the @GeneratedValue annotation for pk sequence, added the @MapsId to the Party attribute of Person, and removed the tree nullable, insertable and updatable annotations from the @JoinColumn. And then it worked. I'm not so sure what I've done now that I didn't do earlier on ... but there must have been something I've forgotten ... It also seems essensial that I do person.setParty(party); It is not enough to party.setPerson(person);

Comment: @user275886 Yes, you need the @GeneratedValue on the parent if you want it to get generated by the DB. And yes, you have to set both sides of the relation between person and party to have things working properly. Glad it's solved.

Comment: Yup, I guess it was setting both sides of the relationship that was the problem. @GeneratedValue has been working all the time. Thanks a bunch :-)

Comment: btw, does anyone know why netbeans doesn't generate correct code in the first place?